# NestJS load class dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nestjs, koa

I have a couple of parser services which I want to load based on condition.

The condition is a version so if the version is 1, Service1 will be loaded if version is 2, Service2 will be loaded, it continues in this pattern.

```js
const version = 1;

// load service class based on version Service1 in this case
```

I could use switch case statement to load the exact service class based on the version but there could be a lot of service classes and it would not be neat.

Is there any way I could do this in nestJs?

Comment: `const parser = require(\`Service${version}.js\`) ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [class provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#class-providers-useclass) or [factory provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory)

```
const serviceProvider = {
  provide: Service,
  useClass:
    version === 1
      ? Service1
      : Service2,
};

@Module({
  providers: [serviceProvider],
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

something like this

```
function serviceFactory(){
   return import(`service-${version}`)
};
```